# SQL query to group fetching other data from that row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a schema as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
  `id` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `c_id` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `d_id` char(32) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('1673b492fe9049a5bda9dcea56e9de6a', '1673b49303d04aadba461c27726f8cb8', '16328bc433604fe0af1329a0c2bc0312');

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('163b75aeafe0479aa426e506c687da91', '1673b49303d04aadba461c27726f8cb8', '15fbace119504b1db81bb6409b77fb26');

INSERT INTO a VALUES ('161ad54eb7f042c584881ed6dec31e68', '16328bc433604fe0af1329a0c2bc0312', '160705a0b0304a02b00ec47c2c84f99b');
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f6ff7d/1)

I require a query which basically looks like
`select c_id, max(id), d_id from a group by c_id`, in which the data is coming from the row which matches `MAX(id)`

Of course, this is not possible in the SQL mode which allows only full group by:

> Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'a.d_id' which is not functionally dependent on
>   columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Is this possible, and how do I do it? Preferably without a join.

Comment: Make use of corelated subquery for matching data coming from the row with max()

Comment: Why do you need without join ? Any specific restrictions ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya simply because I'm trying to remove all joins from the code in preparation for sharding

Comment: @bear ok What is your MySQL server version ? If it is 8.0 and above, we can use Window functions; in older version, we can either use correlated subqueries or user-defined variables. Please confirm the version; I will add more possible approaches.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya MySQL 5.7

Comment: @bear Added another version to the answer utilizing no join. Let know if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html), you can get the maximum values of `id` (latest `id`) for every `c_id`. You can then join this result-set to the main table, to get only the row corresponding to latest `id`.

[**View Query 1 on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pjU9fT6BHMygcdPpCxMpTe/0)

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM a 
JOIN (SELECT c_id, max(id) AS max_id 
      FROM a 
      GROUP BY c_id) AS dt
  ON dt.c_id = a.c_id AND 
     dt.max_id = a.id
```

**Result**

```
| id                               | c_id                             | d_id                             |
| -------------------------------- | -------------------------------- | -------------------------------- |
| 161ad54eb7f042c584881ed6dec31e68 | 16328bc433604fe0af1329a0c2bc0312 | 160705a0b0304a02b00ec47c2c84f99b |
| 1673b492fe9049a5bda9dcea56e9de6a | 1673b49303d04aadba461c27726f8cb8 | 16328bc433604fe0af1329a0c2bc0312 |
```

---

Since you are explicitly looking for a solution not utilizing `JOIN`, we can use [User-defined variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html). We will determine Row number within grouping of `c_id` with highest `id` value having row number 1. Eventually, we will consider only those rows where the row number value is 1. Check further explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308

**Note** that `CROSS JOIN` does not join to an actual table; instead it is a trick to initialize the user-variables within a single query.

One noteworthy point here is that your `c_id` column is defined with `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. So, while initializing the variables we need to explicitly ensure the same character set and collation. Otherwise, we get an error of **"Illegal mix of collations"**. This happens because the string variables are by-default initialized with `utf8mb4_general_ci` collation. We will use [`CAST(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) function to ensure the initialization with `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` instead.

```
SELECT
dt2.id, dt2.c_id, dt2.d_id 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    dt1.id, dt1.c_id, dt1.d_id, 
    @rn := CASE WHEN @cid = dt1.c_id THEN @rn + 1
                WHEN @cid := dt1.c_id THEN 1
           END AS row_num 
  FROM   
  (
     SELECT
       id, c_id, d_id 
     FROM a 
     ORDER BY c_id, id DESC
  ) dt1
  CROSS JOIN 
  (
     SELECT 
       @rn := 0, 
       @cid := CAST('' AS CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci 
  ) AS user_vars 
) dt2 
WHERE dt2.row_num = 1
```

[**View Query 2 on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pjU9fT6BHMygcdPpCxMpTe/1)