# Determine Rank based on Multiple Columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-rank

I have a table which has 3 fields, I want to rank column based on user_id and game_id.

Here is SQL Fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/883e9d/1

the table already I have :

| user_id | game_id | game_detial_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 10 | 1000 |
| 6 | 11 | 260 |
| 7 | 10 | 1200 |
| 7 | 11 | 500 |
| 7 | 12 | 360 |
| 7 | 13 | 50 |

expected output :

| user_id | game_id | game_detial_sum | user_game_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 10 | 1000 | 1 |
| 6 | 11 | 260 | 2 |
| 7 | 10 | 1200 | 1 |
| 7 | 11 | 500 | 2 |
| 7 | 12 | 360 | 3 |
| 7 | 13 | 50 | 4 |

My efforts so far :

```
SET @s := 0; 
SELECT user_id,game_id,game_detail, 
       CASE WHEN user_id = user_id THEN (@s:=@s+1) 
            ELSE @s = 0 
       END As user_game_rank 
FROM game_logs
```

**Edit:** (From OP [Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465111/set-rank-based-on-multiple-columns/53465139#comment93801173_53465111)): Ordering is based on the descending order of `game_detail`

> order of game_detail

Comment: Is the ordering based on ascending order of `game_id` or the descending order of `game_detail` ?

Comment: order of  game_detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subquery inside the `FROM` clause), we order our data such that all the rows having same `user_id` values come together, with further sorting between them based on `game_detail` in Descending order.

Now, we use this result-set and use conditional `CASE..WHEN` expressions to evaluate the row numbering. It will be like a Looping technique (which we use in application code, eg: PHP). We would store the previous row values in the User-defined variables, and then check the current row's value(s) against the previous row. Eventually, we will assign row number accordingly.

**Edit:** Based on MySQL [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and @Gordon Linoff's observation:

> The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is
>   undefined. For example, there is no guarantee that SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1
>   evaluates @a first and then performs the assignment.

We will need to evaluate row number and assign the `user_id` value to `@u` variable within the same expression.

```
SET @r := 0, @u := 0; 
SELECT
  @r := CASE WHEN @u = dt.user_id 
                  THEN @r + 1
             WHEN @u := dt.user_id /* Notice := instead of = */
                  THEN 1 
        END AS user_game_rank, 
  dt.user_id, 
  dt.game_detail, 
  dt.game_id 

FROM 
( SELECT user_id, game_id, game_detail
  FROM game_logs 
  ORDER BY user_id, game_detail DESC 
) AS dt
```

**Result**

```
| user_game_rank | user_id | game_detail | game_id |
| -------------- | ------- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1              | 6       | 260         | 11      |
| 2              | 6       | 100         | 10      |
| 1              | 7       | 1200        | 10      |
| 2              | 7       | 500         | 11      |
| 3              | 7       | 260         | 12      |
| 4              | 7       | 50          | 13      |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hoWE58V5RS4nRSdHsXoPrH/3)

---

An interesting note from MySQL [Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html), which I discovered recently:

> Previous releases of MySQL made it possible to assign a value to a
>   user variable in statements other than SET. This functionality is
>   supported in MySQL 8.0 for backward compatibility but is subject to
>   removal in a future release of MySQL.

Also, thanks to a fellow SO member, came across this blog by MySQL Team: https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/

General observation is that using `ORDER BY` with evaluation of the user variables in the same query block, does not ensure that the values will be correct always. As, MySQL optimizer *may* come into place and change our *presumed* order of evaluation.

Best approach to this problem would be to upgrade to MySQL 8+ and utilize the [`Row_Number()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) functionality:

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
SELECT user_id, 
       game_id, 
       game_detail, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id 
                          ORDER BY game_detail DESC) AS user_game_rank 
FROM game_logs 
ORDER BY user_id, user_game_rank;
```

**Result**

```
| user_id | game_id | game_detail | user_game_rank |
| ------- | ------- | ----------- | -------------- |
| 6       | 11      | 260         | 1              |
| 6       | 10      | 100         | 2              |
| 7       | 10      | 1200        | 1              |
| 7       | 11      | 500         | 2              |
| 7       | 12      | 260         | 3              |
| 7       | 13      | 50          | 4              |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hoWE58V5RS4nRSdHsXoPrH/1)

Answer (score 6):

The best solution in MySQL, prior to version 8.0 is the following:

```
select gl.*, 
       (@rn := if(@lastUserId = user_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@lastUserId := user_id, 1, 1)
                 )
        ) as user_game_rank
from (select gl.*
      from game_logs gl
      order by gl.user_id, gl.game_detail desc
     ) gl cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @lastUserId := 0) params;
```

The ordering is done in a subquery.  This is required starting around MySQL 5.7.  The variable assignments are all in one expression, so different order of evaluation of expressions doesn't matter (and MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions).

Comment: `@lastUserId := user_id` can still be evaluated before the `if()` expression. definitely some trick involved in `if(user_id := @lastUserId`, but unable to understand so. How does that work ? Some explanation would be handy.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . . . That line was a mistake and has been removed.  It is not used in the calculation.

Comment: Makes sense now. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT user_id, game_id, game_detail, 
       CASE WHEN user_id = @lastUserId 
            THEN @rank := @rank + 1 
            ELSE @rank := 1 
       END As user_game_rank,
       @lastUserId := user_id
FROM game_logs
cross join (select @rank := 0, @lastUserId := 0) r
order by user_id, game_detail desc
```

### [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/883e9d/26)

Comment: @GordonLinoff particular blog from MySQL team may be helpful: https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/  2) This answer is wrong because it does not determine the row numbering based on `game_detail` in descending order. It just seem to work, because (unfortunately) OP's *sample* data itself is insufficient (it is already sorted). Thirdly, afaik, evaluation of user variables in this and the other answer (mine) is happening in two different expressions  (separated by comma). Will be happy if specific difference can be showcased

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya: I added an `order by`

Comment: @juergend I will also ask you to read this blog once: https://mysqlserverteam.com/row-numbering-ranking-how-to-use-less-user-variables-in-mysql-queries/ Basically MySQL does not guarantee whether evaluation will happen before `order by` or after (due to its own optimization kicking in).

Comment: @juergend I had a chat with Nick about this kind of problems, and unexpected behaviour in certain scenarios etc, in comments of another question. You may be interested in the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53404473/selecting-best-row-in-each-group-based-on-two-columns/53405484#comment93754272_53405484

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya . . . You're right.  This makes the same mistake yours does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have fixed my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very simple correlated sub query:

```
SELECT *, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT game_detail) + 1
    FROM game_logs AS x
    WHERE user_id = t.user_id AND game_detail > t.game_detail
) AS user_game_rank
FROM game_logs AS t
ORDER BY user_id, user_game_rank
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=212fcf60f3457339495c2b912e1529cb)

It is slower but far more reliable than user variables. All it takes is one JOIN to break them.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to `Madhur Bhaiya` answer, In my use case we expect the rank to be the same when user_id is the same for example,

| user_id | game_id | game_detial_sum | user_game_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 10 | 1000 | 1 |
| 6 | 11 | 260 | 1 |
| 7 | 10 | 1200 | 2 |
| 7 | 11 | 500 | 2 |
| 7 | 12 | 360 | 2 |
| 7 | 13 | 50 | 2 |

The query

```
SET @rank := 0, @last_user_id := 0; 
SELECT
 @rank := CASE WHEN @last_user_id = dt.user_id 
                 THEN @rank
            WHEN @last_user_id := dt.user_id
                 THEN @rank + 1
       END AS user_game_rank, 
 dt.user_id, 
 dt.game_detail, 
 dt.game_id 

FROM (SELECT user_id, game_id, game_detail
 FROM game_logs 
 ORDER BY user_id, game_detail DESC
) AS dt
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use MySql upper 8.0.0,

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY game_detail DESC) FROM game_logs
```