# Generate row numbers and assign same row number to same values

Tags: mysql, sql, dense-rank

I have a requirement to show duplicate row number for duplicate values for every new occurrence.

Sample Table `orders` with column `AGENT_CODE` and i want an expected output to be like

```
Sl  agent_code
------------------
1   A001
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
2   A002
3   A003
3   A003
4   A004
4   A004
4   A004
4   A004
5   A007
5   A007
5   A007
6   A008
6   A008
```

I was able to get the row number with a sequence like 1,2,3,4....19 by writing the query:

```
SET @row_number := 0;
SELECT @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS row_number, AGENT_CODE
FROM orders, (SELECT @row_number := 0) t
ORDER BY agent_code
```

But what I wanted is the row number must be printed in a sequence for every new occurrence as shown in the expected output.

Comment: What MySQL version are you using?

Comment: 5.2.37 MySQL Server

Comment: You need to have an explicit ordering done first in a Derived Table. Read this answer to understand why you are getting wrong results: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something similar to `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AGENT_CODE)` which requires MySQL 8+. In older versions you could simply do this:

```
SELECT AGENT_CODE, (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT AGENT_CODE) + 1
    FROM orders AS x
    WHERE x.AGENT_CODE < t.AGENT_CODE
) AS sn
FROM orders AS t
```

PS: if you want to use user variables then you need another variable called `@prevagent`.

Comment: Shouldn't `WHERE x.AGENT_CODE < t.AGENT_CODE` be `WHERE x.AGENT_CODE <= t.AGENT_CODE`

Comment: No, I forgot to add 1 to `COUNT(*)`.

Comment: hey @Salman A this seems to work, but how would i start from 1, because your output is giving me from 0.