# row_number() in mysql does not return id as i expected

Tags: mysql, row-number

I have a problem with making the equivalent of row_number in mysql.
Here is my code:

```
  SELECT
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @facebookv = a.facebook THEN @row_number:= @row_number + 1
        ELSE @row_number:=1
    END AS num,
   @facebookv:=a.facebook as denumire_facebook,
    a.Keyword,
    sum(a.Sales) as Sales
FROM
    ams_prod a , (SELECT @row_number:=0,@facebookv='') AS t
    group by a.facebook,a.Keyword
    having sum(a.Sales)>0
ORDER BY a.facebook;
```

So the problem is that it is returning me the same "num" for the same "facebook" column value like:

[image]

And no, they are not doubled, they are just repeating a couple of times.
Any idea why is this happening? Thanks!

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. One problem I can see is using `ORDER BY` in the same query block with variables being evaluated in the `SELECT` clause. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308 It should give your noteworthy pointers while approaching a query using variables.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for your answear. It helped me to understand how to use my query block.

Comment: Use MySQL 8.0.  It supports ROW_NUMBER() and other windows functions.

Comment: @oysteing The answer that helped me is in this link stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308 Also I can't upgrade the MySQL version because I work on someone else's server.