# Ranking a table through multiple categories

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking, rank

I am trying to find a way to rank people's scores through multiple categories.
The table contains a list of every player along with the event they participated in, and their score.

The query needs to assign a rank to each player based on score within each event. (The Ranks assigned in Event 1 and Event 2 should be completely separate.)

If the player is missing from an event, they should be assigned a Rank of (Total players in that category + 1)

I can do a basic ranking over 1 category. That's simple. But I don't even have a clue how to do this.

**Data in table**

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| Name   | Score | Event # |
+--------+-------+---------+
| Kevin  | 73    | Event 1 |
| George | 69    | Event 1 |
| Henry  | 70    | Event 1 |
|        |       |         |
| George | 45    | Event 2 |
| Kevin  | 65    | Event 2 |
| Henry  | 65    | Event 2 |
| Daniel | 50    | Event 2 |
+--------+-------+---------+
```

**Expected return**

```
+---------+--------+------+
| Event # | Name   | Rank |
+---------+--------+------+
| Event 1 | Kevin  | 1    |
| Event 1 | Henry  | 2    |
| Event 1 | George | 3    |
| Event 1 | Daniel | 4    |
| Event 2 | Kevin  | 1    |
| Event 2 | Henry  | 1    |
| Event 2 | Daniel | 3    |
| Event 2 | George | 4    |
+---------+--------+------+
```

Note the ranking is NOT dense!
I am on MySql 5.7.

In actuality I have over 50 events and hundreds of people.

This is what I have for ranking 1 event

```sql
SELECT
        IF( SCORE =@_last_rank,@curRank:=@curRank,@curRank:=@_sequence) AS RANK,
        NAME,
        EVENT,
        @_sequence:=@_sequence+1,@_last_rank:= SCORE
        FROM (SELECT * FROM database WHERE EVENT = $event) p, 
        (SELECT @curRank := 1, @_sequence:=1, @_last_rank:=0) r
        ORDER BY  RANK, NAME
```

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: "I can do a basic ranking over 1 category. That's simple." - Please code the corresponding code.

Comment: Do you have a master table for all the "Name" ? Also check this answer, for general approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53465139/2469308

Comment: I added the code @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Where are you handling "If the player is missing from an event, they should be assigned a Rank of (Total players in that category + 1)" in your code?

Comment: I can't figure that part out. In my description I mentioned I could do basic ranking. This is as far as I could get. I'm still very new to SQL @PaulSpiegel

Comment: Your query is [not doing](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nTbu2GfAoihjDRyWbXcTdS/0) what you want. For the start you need [ORDER BY in the subquery](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bcTS1PZMGD8HSBrCFRt1nx/0).

Comment: You should really consider to solve that in application code or switch to a new version with window functions. When I see the common solutions with user variables, my eyes hurt.

Answer (score 0):

This sql statement

```
Select eventno,Name,rank 
From 
 (Select eventno,Name,
            CASE 
              WHEN @event = eventno THEN @rownum := @rownum + 1
              ELSE 
                  @rownum := 1
             END as rank,
             @event := eventno
      From table1 t
      JOIN (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
      JOIN (SELECT @event := (Select Eventno from table1 Limit 1)) s
  ORDER BY t.eventno,t.score) x;


  CREATE TABLE table1
  (`Name` varchar(6), `Score` int, `Eventno` varchar(7)) 

  INSERT INTO table1
(`Name`, `Score`, `Eventno`)
VALUES
('Kevin', 73, 'Event 1'),
('George', 69, 'Event 1'),
('Henry', 70, 'Event 1'),
('George', 45, 'Event 2'),
('Kevin', 65, 'Event 2'),
('Henry', 65, 'Event 2'),
('Daniel', 50, 'Event 2')
```

Gives following result:

```
  eventno   Name    rank
  Event 1   George  1
  Event 1   Henry   2
  Event 1   Kevin   3
  Event 2   George  1
  Event 2   Daniel  2
  Event 2   Kevin   3
  Event 2   Henry   4
  7 rows
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach avoids the (non reriable) use of user variables and highly complex queries. It is using temporary tables and utilizing MyISAM's *AUTO_INCREMENT per group* feature, to generate row numbers per group. To get the rank from the row numbers a GROUP BY query with `MIN(row_number)` is used.

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_scores;
create temporary table tmp_scores(
  rn int auto_increment,
  event varchar(50),
  name varchar(50),
  score int,
  primary key (event, rn)
)engine=myisam;

insert into tmp_scores(event, name, score)
  select e.event, n.name, t.score
  from (select distinct t.event from mytable t) e
  cross join (select distinct t.name from mytable t) n
  left join mytable t on t.event = e.event and t.name = n.name
  order by e.event, t.score is null, t.score desc;

drop temporary table if exists tmp_rank_by_score;
create temporary table tmp_rank_by_score(
  event varchar(50),
  score int,
  rank int,
  primary key (event, rank)
)engine=myisam;

insert into tmp_rank_by_score(event, score, rank)
  select event, score, min(rn) as rank
  from tmp_scores
  group by event, score;

select s.event, s.name, s.score, r.rank
from tmp_scores s
join tmp_rank_by_score r on r.event = s.event and r.score <=> s.score
order by r.event, r.rank;

drop temporary table if exists tmp_rank_by_score;
drop temporary table if exists tmp_scores;
```

Result:

```
| event   | name   | score | rank |
| ------- | ------ | ----- | ---- |
| Event 1 | Kevin  | 73    | 1    |
| Event 1 | Henry  | 70    | 2    |
| Event 1 | George | 69    | 3    |
| Event 1 | Daniel |       | 4    |
| Event 2 | Kevin  | 65    | 1    |
| Event 2 | Henry  | 65    | 1    |
| Event 2 | Daniel | 50    | 3    |
| Event 2 | George | 45    | 4    |
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uNVucT5L1iqBV1Mg3eWwa2/0)