# Generate an integer sequence in MySQL with random order

Tags: mysql

Is there any other way to generate sequence_no with order by random in MYSQL???
I have a table: captcha

```
SET @a:= 1;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 as sequence_no,captcha_id, captcha_name
FROM captcha,(SELECT @a:= 0) AS a
ORDER BY RAND()
```

my expected output :

```
sequence_no | captcha_id | captcha_name 
----------------------------------------
01          | 11         | name1
02          | 06         | name2
```

my query output :

```
sequence_no | captcha_id | captcha_name
---------------------------------------- 
11           | 11          | name1
06           | 06          | name2
```

Comment: You are setting `@a` twice in the SQL, once in the `SET` and once in the `CROSS JOIN`..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes that was my mistake..thank you for your reply but if I remove the cross join or one of them then also I can't get my expected output. But I got Solution of the derived table, working nicely for me.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya answer  `SELECT @a:=@a+1 as sequence_no,
       dt.captcha_id, 
       dt.captcha_name 
FROM (
       SELECT captcha_id, captcha_name 
       FROM captcha 
       ORDER BY RAND()
     ) AS dt CROSS JOIN(SELECT @a:= 0)` with a CROSS JOIN should work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you will first need to perform explicit random-sorting inside a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/derived-tables.html). Then, use the subquery result, to set a sequence number (for the random sorted rows):

```
SET @a:= 0;
SELECT @a:=@a+1 as sequence_no,
       dt.captcha_id, 
       dt.captcha_name 
FROM (
       SELECT captcha_id, captcha_name 
       FROM captcha 
       ORDER BY RAND()
     ) AS dt
```

Comment: the outer SQL needs to have `ORDER BY @a` or `ORDER BY sequence_no` ...

Comment: @RaymondNijland no I dont think so. Sequence number need to be in ascending order only (as per OP). He just needs the other records to be in random order..

Comment: *"no I dont think so"* SQL resultsets are by ANSI/ISO definition **orderless**, besides the topicstarter resultset seams to be sorted on the `sequence_no` on the expected output..

Comment: @RaymondNijland I know; but in this particular case, we are computing sequence number on-the-fly, so they are bound to be in the ascending order only. So far, in all the problems involving row number/rank etc using variables, I have never found the need for explicit sorting (again) at the outermost level.

Comment: @RaymondNijland eventually the only solution is to upgrade to MySQL 8.0; and avoid using user variables :-)  I did write an answer on this sometime back, trying to be as safe as possible when using variables (offcourse not 100%). You can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53465111/determine-rank-based-on-multiple-columns-in-mysql/53465139#53465139

Comment: *"So far, in all the problems involving row number/rank etc using variables, I have never found the need for explicit sorting (again) at the outermost level. "* Yea most likely the MySQL Optimizer chooses to use the delivered table order as final "sort" to deliver fast results..